# Unable to install npm for version problem in vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

How can I solve this problem!

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MOA\agri-app> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vito-vue@3.0.1
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^2.6.11" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.0.0" from @tinymce/tinymce-vue@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@tinymce/tinymce-vue
npm ERR!   @tinymce/tinymce-vue@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-27T17_53_48_498Z-debug.log
```

Comment: your need to install tinymce-vue v3.2.0 as ^4.0.0 requires vue3, which your not using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068336/14344959

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference here: [[BUG] Could not resolve peerDependencies of matching semver ranges](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2999) which might help you out on your case.

The step fixed issue was:

1. uninstall vite
2. install vue@3
3. install vite back.

I also encountered the same situation, since I was working on a brand new project, `npm install vue@3` helped me out, but if you are not migrating from vue@2 to vue@3, this may not be the best option.

---

Can you check your node version? I found that **downgrading to node v12 can resolve the problem**, and I was able to install all the dependencies after downgrading to v12. Seems like the later version can cause the problem.

Comment: Yes it was the node version issue. I had node v16 in my pc. But when i unistall node and installed a older version v14 it works.

Comment: I encountered same problem, and I was using v14, somehow downgrading to v12 helped me out. If you ever encountered the same issue on v14, you can try downgrading to v12. Among all the teammates who also using v14, I'm the only one having this problem. @AshrafulIslam