# laravel 9 : could not resolve peerDependencies during install reactJs & VueJs using laravel/ui

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, npm, laravel-9, laravel-ui

I installed [Laravel/Ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) in Fresh Laravel 9 for setup **ReactJs**

I was run below commands step by step in cli

```
composer require laravel/ui  

php artisan ui react

npm install
```

now when i run `npm install` command then it throw error about "unable to resolve dependency tree" as like below

```
microtech-007@microtech-007:/var/www/html/laravel-cms$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-react@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-react@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/microtech-007/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/microtech-007/.npm/_logs/2023-01-10T09_34_09_381Z-debug-0.log
```

---

additional :- if you tried to setup **VueJs** using **laravel/ui** then you may got error as like below during running the `npm install` command

```
microtech-007@microtech-007:/var/www/html/laravel-cms$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/microtech-007/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/microtech-007/.npm/_logs/2023-01-10T09_54_29_026Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you faced issue during setup **ReactJs / VueJs** using laravel/ui

then follow below step

**For ReactJs**

> Step 1 Remove "@vitejs/plugin-react" package. Run `npm un @vitejs/plugin-react`

Now, try to run `npm install` command. it successfully installing all packages.

then after install "@vitejs/plugin-react" package again as a **DevDependecies**

> Step 2 :- `npm i @vitejs/plugin-react --save-dev` **OR** `npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-react`

Done ... Now you can use `npm run dev` OR `npm run build`

---

**For VueJs**

> Step 1 Remove "@vitejs/plugin-vue" package. Run `npm un @vitejs/plugin-vue`

Now, try to run `npm install` command. it successfully installing all packages.

then after install "@vitejs/plugin-vue" package again as a **DevDependecies**

> Step 2 :- `npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue --save-dev` **OR** `npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-vue`

Done ... Now you can use `npm run dev` OR `npm run build`

I hope this one helps to someone

References :- [[BUG] Could not resolve peerDependencies of matching semver ranges](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2999#issuecomment-812347764)

Comment: for Npm related other error references see here may this one helps to you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719468/14344959